# Pass variable value from js file to other js file in routes Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

```js
//A.js file

exports.sign = function(req, res)
{
 var uname = req.body.uname;
 var pwd = req.body.pwd;
 var fname = req.body.fname;
 var lname = req.body.lname;
 var dob = req.body.dob;
 var gend = req.body.gender;
 
 res.render('./login', {'title':'Welcome'});
};

//B.js

exports.signin = function(req, res)
{
 var unamec = req.body.user;
 var pwdc = req.body.pwd;
 console.log(uname);
 
 if(uname === unamec && pwd === pwdc)
 {
  /*res.render('logged', {
   'title':'Welcome',
   'fname':fname,
   'lname':lname,
   'dob':dob,
   'gend':gend
  });*/
  res.send('Done');
 }else {
  res.render('fail', {'title':'Login Error'});
 }
}
```

I want to pass variable values of uname, pwd, fname, lname, dob, gend from A.js to B.js file. I want to make it global so that it can be accessed from B.js or other js files in routes folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up a message listener in B, and send a message from A. You'll need to attach to a window or compatible object, in B.js:

```
    window.addEventListener('message',
        function (event) {
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                // Do whatever
            } catch (exception) {
                // Didn't work
            }
        }
    );
```

In A.js:

```
// This you could call on some event and provide the parameters
function update(uname, pwd, fname, lname, dob, gend)
{
    if (window.opener)
    {
        var data = 
        {
            'uname':uname,
            'pwd':pwd,
            'fname':fname,
            'lname':lname,
            'dob':dob,
            'gend':gend
        };
        window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), '*');
    }
}
```

So in this case, the window running a script B.js needs to open another window running A.js.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I am looking for an answer that is less complicated. Maybe using exports function